# How to get smooth fonts in SVG graphics generated through a WolframScript script?

Tags: front-end, fonts, scripting, svg-format

Below are screenshots of the x-axis labels plots generated and exported in SVG format using exactly the same code, either "interactively" or "programmatically":

**interactively**

[image]

**programmatically**

[image]

By "interactively" I mean that the code was run during an interactive session, in a *Mathematica* notebook.  By "programmatically" I mean that the code was run by a `WolframScript` script executed on the Unix command line.

Note that the interactive version produces smooth fonts, while the programmatic one produces jagged bit-mapped fonts.

**How can I get the script to produce the smooth letters I get in the front end?**

---

If you want to reproduce a similar result, follow these steps:

First, define the following function in the *Mathematica* front-end

```
exportChart[file_] := (
   SeedRandom[0];
   Export[file,
    Framed[
     BoxWhiskerChart[
      Table[
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, 1], 100], {mu, {0, 3, 2, 5}}]
      , ImageSize -> 75
      , ImageMargins -> 30
      , BarOrigin -> Left
      ]
     , FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]
     ]
    ]);
```

...and invoke it with a suitable filepath as argument; for example:

```
exportChart["/tmp/frontend.svg"];
```

Next, copy the code for `exportChart` to a *text* file (e.g. `save_svg.wl`), and add an invocation of `exportChart` with a different filepath as argument; for example:

```
(* file: save_svg.wl *)

exportChart[file_] := (
   SeedRandom[0];
   Export[file,
    Framed[
     BoxWhiskerChart[
      Table[
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mu, 1], 100], {mu, {0, 3, 2, 5}}]
      , ImageSize -> 75
      , ImageMargins -> 30
      , BarOrigin -> Left
      ]
     , FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]
     ]
    ]);

exportChart["/tmp/cli.svg"];
```

Now run this script using the `WolframScript` interpreter.  In Unix, this would be something like this:

```
$ WolframScript -script save_svg.wl
```

Now you should have two *.svg files which should, in principle, be identical.  For me at least, they aren't, due to font differences like those shown above.

This is what my `/tmp/frontend.svg` and `/tmp/cli.svg` look like.

**/tmp/frontend.svg**

[image]

**/tmp/cli.svg**

[image]

---

**NB:** The business with the zero-opacity frame in `exportChart` is voodoo that *somehow* avoids a *Mathematica* bug that occasionally results in malformed SVG exports.

Comment: On Windows 10 with 11.0.1 I believe my .svg's look identical, FWIW. Consider http://imgur.com/a/Dk0DO, left from wolframscript, right generated by evaluating the same code in a notebook.

Comment: @user6014: Thanks for checking!